# Транзакция для вставки и обновления этих же данных

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Подскажите.
Могу ли я сделать встаку и в этой же транзакции сделать обновление этих же данных?
На serverless  MySQL.
Бо при попытке выполнить такой запрос я получаю ошибку. DeadLock.
Выполняя это в очереди.

Comment: Можете. . . . .

Comment: @andreymal изменил чуть вопрос

Comment: Если INSERT и UPDATE действительно выполняются в одной транзакции, то они не могут организовать дедлок сами по себе даже теоретически. Только если пересечься с другой транзакцией...